# Lucene IndexSearcher always return 20 ScoreDocs

Tags: lucene

Hello I have such a piece of code

```
IndexSearcher iSearcher = new IndexSearcher(dir);
TopDocs docs = iSearcher.search(parsedQuery,filter, 9);
```

I always get 20 scoredocs. Could anyone help?

Comment: you mean docs.scoreDocs.length == 20 ? What version of Lucene are you using?

Comment: I'm using Lucene from Compass (where JDBC directory is implemented) as I need to store index in the DB. NOt sure what version of Lucene is used there. Actually there is no difference what number I set to the search method - I get always 20 ScoreDocs inside TopDocs

Answer (score 0):

1) Do you always get back exactly 20 ScoreDocs? As your search limits the result to 9 ScoreDocs, I am curious about the '20 ScoreDocs'.

2) Have you verified that your index contains Lucene terms that would result in more than 20 ScoreDocs? I have found it useful after changing my indexing strategy to test the index with Luke before performing any other testing.

Answer (score 0):

Just because doc.scoreDocs.length == 20 doesn't mean that you have received 20 results. You must check each individual result's doc id not to be equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is used as a 'no result here' sentinel value. The point of all this is typical of Lucene -- minimizing memory allocation, in this case by reusing already allocated result arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. Problem was in build path actually. It cantains not exisiting library and project could not be built. That is why every time I tried to change code and debug it, previously built version was used.

Sorry for misleading.